# OnClickListener on non-Mainactivity & change first activity

Tags: android, authentication, onclicklistener

i've a problem. I want to make a app with a loggin activity and a main activity. (To the OnClickListiner later)

fist:

What ive done so far:

- i've created a login. java and login.xml
  login.java:

  ```
  public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
      Button btnStartAnotherActivity;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.login);

          boolean hasLogedIn = true;
          if (hasLogedIn) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
              finish();
          } else {
          }
      }


      public void onClick(View view) {
          //calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
          Intent inent = new Intent("android.name.MainActivity ");

          startActivity(inent);
      }
  }
  ```
- i've created a MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml
- moreover i've some other java and xml files to make a materiel designed Tab view for my MainActivity.
- i have 3 tabs thats how it looks so far

[![tab1 with buttons][1]][1]

-now i'be added to the first tab 3 buttons.

example of one button: (the others are the same just a other id )

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kommt"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/kommt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space" />
```

-So the app is running now without problems. ( All Tabs and there content is showing like i want it )

- when i build the project the mainactivity is open first( see that link of the picture )
- HOW TO SET: the login interface to be started once, when starting the app for the first time. After login is succesfully, then the mainactivity will always open. Thats my first problem. What should i add to the Login.java ? and how to set that the login.xml starts before the mainactivity ?

Second:

As i told you ive added some buttons. To test the buttons i've tried to implement a code for toast notification when clicking on button. But every time i build the project with the toast notifitcation code, the app doenst start anymore. Here the code for the toast notification i'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener { 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // but my main_activity doesnt have buttons ... tab1.xml have b

Button kommtbutton;

kommtbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.kommt);
        kommtbutton.setOnClickListener(this);}



@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        setContentView(R.layout.tab1); // not sure if this is right ive did it cause the buttons are in the tab1 layout and not main_activity

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.kommt:
            {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Eingestempelt",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast1.show();
                break;
            } ....}
```

here i have implemented all 3 buttons in a switch case.

It looks right but the onclicklistinier seems to kill my application before it can start. Maybe someone can help me.

i have following files:

Login.java, MainActivity.java, Tab1.java,Tab2.java,Tab3.java, SlidingTabsLayout.java, SlidingTabStrip.java and ViewPagerAdaper.

and i have this layouts.

acitivy_main.xml, login.xml, tab1,tab2,tab3.xml, toolbar.xml.

I'm not allowed to send pictures cause i'm new here.

Where have i do implement the code for the toast notification ?

thats my activity_main:xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<android_package.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

and this is my tab1.xml

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Tabs"
    android:background="#FDFDFE"
    >



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/buchungen"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Geht"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/geht"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buchungen" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Status:"
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Letzte Buchung:"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/letzteBuchung"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buchungen"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="314dp"
            android:layout_height="310dp"
            android:id="@+id/profilbild"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/time" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/geht"
        android:id="@+id/space" />

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kommt"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/kommt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Pause An/Aus"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pause" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Einstempeln"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kommt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Ausstempeln"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/geht"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/geht"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:textColor="#190707"
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kommt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The buttons are in the tab1.xml. Where have i to acces them to make a Interaction ( show toast when pressing the button ) ? in the MainActivity.java or the Tab1.java or somewhere else ?

When i try to add toast notification my app just kills itself ...

Comment: Vitja, please do not use Google Drive to display images, no one has permission to view https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EdZ8mF6GzzYnFNUlRzbXdoNmM/view?usp=drive_web. Please use Stack Overflow's built-in image upload features instead.

Comment: oh thanks i dont know that. i totally new here sry.

Comment: Did you use any API call for authentication?

Comment: i will call it from a webserver. i'm not sure where to add the authentication code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all the findViewById and setContentView in the onCreate method or they won't do the job.

First point :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    // Layout elements
    private Button kommtbutton = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Attach layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // but my main_activity doesnt have buttons ... tab1.xml have b

        // Retrieve layout elements
        kommtbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.kommt);

        // Attach listeners
        kommtbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Do not use getApplicationContext(), this is an activity
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Eingestempelt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    [...]
}
```

Second point :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    // Layout elements
    private EditText edit_login = null;
    private EditText edit_password = null;
    private Button btn_login = null;

    // Class variables
    private SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check if the user is already logged in
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Attach layout
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        // Retrieve layout elements
        edit_login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_login);
        edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        // Attach listeners
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // Retrieve information
                String login = edit_login.getText().toString();
                String password = edit_password.getText().toString();

                // Do job
                boolean canConnect = true; // TODO
                if (canConnect)
                {
                    // Update prefs
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true).commit();

                    // Move to activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update prefs
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false).commit();

                    // Display error message
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Wrong crendentials", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that look very nice. I did it like you wrote it here. to the first point: i've tried it and this statement does not for me:  Toast.makeText(this, "Eingestempelt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ... it tells me that i cant use only this in mainactivity.  To the second point. where i have i to declare the pref variable ? and on which point i can start to ask the server for login data ?

Comment: thats the massage i get on the toast massage: cannot resolve method 'makeText(anoymous andoird.view.View.OnClickListener,java.lang.string,int' and on this: Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); i get the massage:  cannot resolve method 'makeText(anoymous andoird.view.View.OnClickListener,java.lang.Class<name_of_pakage_MainActivity>

Comment: Change `Toast.makeText(this, "Eingestempelt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Eingestempelt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Same in LoginAcitvity : `Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this`

Comment: I corrected my previous answer, the context was missing.

Comment: @Vitja If the answser fits, please mark your question as resolved.

Comment: thanks ive tried it but when i click on login button my app force closes. Could it be that i have to wirte the toast notification & onClickListiner to the Tab1.java and not the MainActivity. java ?

Comment: Yes you should write the toast notification and onClickListiner in the TabActivity not in the parent activity.

Comment: hmmmm ok and how can i introduce onclicklistiner to tab ? thats how my Tab1.class beginns: public class Tab1 extends Fragment { ...} but i need something like that: public class Tab1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {...} ..... when i use this i get an error ...class Tab1 must either be declared or implement abstract method on oncklick(view) in onclicklistiner .... how to fix that :/

Comment: Please update your question with the code that doesn't work. Tabs required Fragment to work.